# How can I check if a node is hit by light or not?

Tags: ios, scenekit

currently I have one light, a plane, and a cube, and another node that I want to check if its not getting hit by light. I want to check If the entire node itself is not getting hit by light. The node is a single element and not in a hierarchy.

Comment: Do you want to know if a (a specific) point on the surface is in shadow? Or, do you want to know if any point on the surface is in shadow? Or, do you want to know if the full surface is in shadow? Does the node only contain a single element or a hierarchy? As it currently stands, it's hard to tell exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Also, there is a difference between not being hit by light and being in the shadow of another object. For example, a spotlight pointing to the left doesn't cast its light on nodes that are right of it.

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear, Do you think you can answer it now??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lighting is something that happens on the GPU. Even if you're working directly with OpenGL or similar in your own engine, finding out something about lighting results isn't often something that's very straightforward or efficient to do.

That said, depending on what exactly you want to know (and how often you need to know about it), there are some approximations that might be useful.

- For a spot light, call the view's [`isNodeInsideFrustum:withPointOfView:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNSceneRenderer/isNodeInsideFrustum:withPointOfView:) method, passing the node you want to know about for the first parameter and the node with the spot light as the second. This tells you if any part of the node's bounding box is in the area "seen" by the light (but not if there are any other nodes in between to occlude the light).
- Check the [`attenuationEndDistance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNLight_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNLight/attenuationEndDistance) for the light against the distance to the node's `position` (or to the corners of its bounding box).
- Use [`hitTestWithSegmentFromPoint:toPoint:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNNode/hitTestWithSegmentFromPoint:toPoint:options:) to examine a ray that starts at the light and ends at the node (either its `position` or bounding box corners). If the hit test finds the node, the light can reach it (modulo attenuation). If the hit test finds another node first, the node you care about is at least partly in shadow.

Trying variations or combinations of these tricks might get you what you're looking for, or something close enough. But beware: there tests have a CPU time cost, so you might not want to be doing one (or several) of them every frame.